# Css Transactions - Hide without fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a css animation like this:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
-transition: all 0.1s linear;
```

I use it to give a responsive effect when switching tabs like:

```
$("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(500);
$("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
```

The things is, I need a way in JS to completely hide this element without being affected by the transaction, instantly. I'm using:

```
document.getElementById("login-container").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

But it takes 0.1s to hide. Is there a way to hide instantly without having to remove the fade effect?

Comment: `$("#register-form").hide()`?

Comment: Hi Pedro, can you make a jsFiddle to make your question more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`document.getElementById("login-container").style.display = "none";`

When you set the display of an element to none, it hides it completely on the page and disregards and animation effects.

Another suggestion is in your CSS, try to specify what properties you want to have the animation effect:

```
-webkit-transition: {properties} 0.1s linear;
-moz-transition: {properties} 0.1s linear;
-transition: {properties} 0.1s linear;
```

Remove the `visibility` from the scope of this and it won't animate when you change it explicitly in your JavaScript.